# Two models, one shows accented character, another one shows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicode

Using RoR 2.3.8.

I have two models. It's strange that when I typed text and saved in Model A, it shows the exact text, but when I do this in Model B, it shows `???`. It's most likely one supports UTF-8 but another doesn't. The thing is, I don't remember me setting any on either. What can I do to fix this?

Using Mac OS 10.6.7, Chrome

Comment: Are you by any chance using mysql? (and please post more information such as OS and locale)

Comment: Is the data stored correctly in the database? And are both model_as and model_bs tables set as UTF8?

Comment: @Augusto, I don't use any locale. @berkes, how do I set those tables as UTF8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL and other database engines set the encoding used for text on several levels: server, database, table and column. Generally the defaults are applied from the top down, from server to database, database to table and so forth, but they can be customized at any given point as required. Sometimes this happens inadvertently and can cause issues.

One way to know what encoding is currently active is to use a client like [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/) which will expose this information to you, or to investigate using the `mysql` command line tool:

```
SHOW CREATE DATABASE example;
```

You get a response that contains something like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE `example` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci */
```

In this case it's a UTF-8 table with UTF-8 UNICODE collation. The encoding defines how thae data is stored and the collation defines how to handle sorting and case conversion.

Investigating further you can examine the table and columns:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE example;
```

This gives a lot more detail, something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `example` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_example_on_email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=29 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

In this case the table itself is defaulting to UTF-8 and the email column is likewise flagged. You may have a column that's different.

If you need to alter the encoding or collation you can use the `ALTER TABLE` statement to effect this.

Comment: Thanks. I just checked with Sequel Pro and found out there's only one table using UTF8, which is Model A. What is the quickest way to change the other tables' encoding to UTF8, which are currently using latin1?

Comment: Nvm, I just clicked using Sequel Pro or phpMyAdmin. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, a front-end tool like that will create the `ALTER TABLE` statement for you. If you're curious, Sequel Pro does show a log of what it actually did.